# Kubernetes nodeport not visible as listening on host but service working

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networking

I have a service running on kubernetes exposed via nodeport like so:

```
test-service                        NodePort    100.100.246.5     <none>        30005:30005/TCP
```

That service is reachable from other nodes and is working properly; however, I don't see see that kubernetes listening on that port if I do a `netstat -tunlp | grep 30005`.

I have `External Traffic Policy:  Local`, and if I understand correctly that should mean that the node with the pod on it should be listening on said port? Again, everything works, but I'm trying to figure out why I cannot see the port listening on the host.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kubernetes services are not implemented as processes listening on a specific port. Instead iptables (or IPVS) is used and services are basically iptables rules. That's why they won't show up in your netstat. You can find more info about it [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-iptables).